# linq query to fetch 1st record from group

Tags: sql, linq, crm

I have a list of records of the contact entity table where each contact has an accountID.
I need to fectch the contact record for each account (in accounts lists) which has less gpa.

here is my try:

```
var stud = (from s in crm.contact
            where s.accountID != null && accountList.Contains(s.accountID.Id)
            orderby s.gpa
            group s by s.accountID.Id into stugrp
            select new contactTest
            {
                account= stugrp.First().account.Id,
                gpa= stugrp.First().gpa.Value
            }).Distinct().ToList();
```

accountList = list of accountid's.

Here I'm getting invalid where condition error.
any help?

Comment: can you share the error?

Comment: What is the type of `Contact.AccountId`, does it refer to a primary key of an Account? Does this `AccountId` also have a property `Id`? Does the `AccountId` have other properties?

Comment: error is {"Invalid 'where' condition. An entity member is invoking an invalid property or method."}

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse yes accountid is the primary key of account.